# datastax opscenter posturl.conf is not posting alerts to an AWS api gateway endpoint

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, aws-api-gateway, opscenter

I am trying to post Opscenter alerts to an AWS Api Gateway endpoint(which is of the form https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/opscenteralerts/alerts). I was able to post to api gateway endpoint from flask server.I also tried posting the opscenter alerts to another webserver.But I am not able to post it to an API Gateway endpoint. I have checked my security groups and API endpoint is open as well.Am I missing anything?

The below is the stack trace in opscenterd.log

```
2017-07-04 18:58:06,651 [opscenterd] ERROR: [Errno 1] Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 149, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/legacy_ssl.py", line 645, in doConnect
    self._connectDone()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/legacy_ssl.py", line 1182, in _connectDone
    self.startTLS(self.ctxFactory)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/legacy_ssl.py", line 542, in startTLS
    if LegacyConnection.startTLS(self, ctx, client):
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 50, in startTLS
    self.socket = JConnection(ctx.getContext(), self.socket, False)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/JythonSSLWrapper.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._wrapped_socket = self._create_client_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/JythonSSLWrapper.py", line 107, in _create_client_socket
    return self._context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/jvm/jython-standalone-2.7.0.9.jar/Lib/ssl.py", line 991, in wrap_socket
    return SSLSocket(sock=sock, server_side=server_side,
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/jvm/jython-standalone-2.7.0.9.jar/Lib/ssl.py", line 521, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/jvm/jython-standalone-2.7.0.9.jar/Lib/ssl.py", line 630, in do_handshake
    self._sock._handle_channel_future(handshake, "SSL handshake", wait=True)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/jvm/jython-standalone-2.7.0.9.jar/Lib/_socket.py", line 365, in handle_exception
    raise _map_exception(jlx)
 (MainThread)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most SSL handshake errors with API Gateway are caused by the client not supporting SNI.  API Gateway requires SNI and will not work without it.  Does Opscenter support SNI?